# readdir() showing non visible files

Tags: c++, c, linux, readdir, dirent.h

I am using readdir() in Ubuntu to display files and directories. The weird thing is readdir() displays some files starting with "dot", and some that end at ~ . But these files are not in my specified directory.

What are these files?

I was wondering when reading names of files, will these weird files will also be mentioned by d_name or not?

[image]

Regards

Comment: The filenames endng in ~ are recovery files used by the editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`readdir` reads all files present within the folder, while `ls` only list non-hidden files. Try to list your files with `ls -a`, and you will see those files.

Comment: but I am planning to write a program which finds files in directories and mentions their path. Is there a way to ignore them.

Comment: Simply add a condition testing if the file you are about to print starts with a dot or not.

Comment: @UmerFarooq `if (filename[0] != '.' && filename[strlen(filename) - 1] != '~')`

Comment: I thought there were some kind of system call. Anyhow I am glad i was thinking the same to put a conditional statment.

Answer (score 1):

By convention, files whose names start with a dot are hidden in Unix-like operating systems (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory#Unix_and_Unix-like_environments)).

You can of course check for the dot at the beginning of the filenames produced by readdir, and simply not return/output those.

Comment: The shell with glob expansion and `ls` agree to hide them by not including them in `*.*` expansions or the default output of a directory.  There's no other sense in which they're hidden, and `readdir()` would be useless if it did not return all the names. One possible alternative design would have two variants such as `readdir()` and `readdir_hidden()` so that you could really see everything when you need to but not by default.  But minimalism in the interface indicates that the current design is better.